# Very low Upload speed support on my Shared DSL Line?

Tags: adsl, internet-speed

I am having confusion that why am I getting too much minimum upload speed support on my ADSL Shared Line as...Is it due to ADSL technology that is supports that much minimum Upload speed which is almost like 1.5 Mbps only..!

Or what is the reason then?

My Modem Statistics:

[image: Modem Statistics Screenshot Link]

To be clear as you can see that my Downstream support is also not much but it's due to the reason that my line is weak but besides I have seen strong lines which Downstream support was like 24000 Kbps but still they were getting that same 1330 Kbps Upstream speed..!

Comment: ISP's typically provision upstream bandwidth much slower, so that you won't be tempted to run a server from that location.  As cloud storage evolves, ISPs are finally being forced to rethink this...

Comment: That's normal (depending of course on what your contract with your ISP says). The A in ADSL stands for Asymmetric. ADSL2+ extends the capability of basic ADSL by doubling the number of downstream channels. The data rates can be as high as 24 Mbit/s downstream and up to 1.4 Mbit/s upstream depending on the distance from the DSLAM to the customer's premises. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITU_G.992.5